# $f$ is strictly convex $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is strongly convex

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis

I want to show that for $$f(x)=x^TAx+b^Tx+c$$ with $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ symmetric, $x,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$: $f$ is strictly convex $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is strongly convex

Additionally to the other known definitions, I know that

$f$ stricly convex $\Leftrightarrow$ $d^T\nabla^2 f(x) d > 0$ for all $x\in X,d\in \mathbb{R}^n$

$f$ strongly convex $\Leftrightarrow$ $\exists\mu >0:$ $d^T \nabla^2 f(x)d \geq \mu \|d\|^2$ for all $x\in X, d\in \mathbb{R}^n$

---

My attempt:

Let $f$ be stricly convex. I already know that $\nabla^2 f = 2A$, so $$2d^TAd>0 \quad \forall x,d\in \mathbb{R}^n, d\neq 0$$
$\Rightarrow$ $0< d^TAd=z\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Setting $z:=\mu \|d\|^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ strongly convex, right?

If $f$ is strongly convex, then $$2d^TAd \geq \mu \|d\|^2 \quad \text{for a }\mu>0$$
Since $\|d\|^2 >0$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $d\neq 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mu\|d\|^2>0$ $\forall d\neq 0$

$$\Rightarrow 2d^TAd \geq \mu \|d\|^2>0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. In that case, those properties are equivalent.

Comment: Your proof is not complete. If $f$ is strictly convex, you just pulled a $\mu$ out of thin air. You need to justify that.

Comment: As an aside: strongly convex always implies strictly convex.

Comment: @copper.hat okay, so $z\in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $\|d\|^2\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Then $\exists \mu>0: z= \mu\|d\|^2$

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, now I see. I've to find a $\mu$ for all $d$

Comment: That is not sufficient, it needs to be uniform.

Comment: The result is true, of course, You could argue by continuity with appropriate choices.

Comment: @copper.hat So you mean if I know that $d^TAd>0$ and $\|d\|^2>0$ for all $d\neq 0$ then I can find a sufficient small $\mu>0$ s.t. $2d^TAd\geq \mu\|d\|$ $\forall d\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @copper.hat I've a better idea. I can choose $\mu = \frac{2d^TAd}{\|d\|^2}>0$ since numerator and denominator are greater than $0$.  Then $2d^TAd\geq \mu\|d\|^2=2d^TAd$

Comment: @copper.hat forget it, I got confused again by uniformity of $\mu$

Comment: Minimise $d^T Ad $ for $\|d\| = 1$.

Comment: Your definition of strictly convex is not equivalent with the standard one. Under your definition $x \mapsto x^4$ would not be strictly convex ...